# Return value to textbox from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, ado.net

Having trouble returning the value ID value I need for output back to the textbox in the form. Webforms and ADO.net

I tried adding a param identity as an int and OUT clause, while setting identity = scope_identity and returning the value then using the pattern my team is currently using for `ExecuteNonQuery` with anonymous parameter classes passing in values and tried passing the @identity value to the textbox.text for the id.

```
DataManager.Db.ExecuteNonQuery("DefaultConnection", "usp_CreateNewSalesTerritory", 
                        new SqlParameter("@orgId", orgId),
                        new SqlParameter("@identity", salesTerritoryIdTextBox.Text),
                        new SqlParameter("@salesTerritoryName", salesTerritories.Name), 
                        new SqlParameter("@createdBy", salesTerritories.CreatedBy), 
                        new SqlParameter("@createdDate", salesTerritories.CreatedDate),
                        new SqlParameter("@updatedBy", salesTerritories.UpdatedBy),
                        new SqlParameter("@updatedDate", salesTerritories.UpdatedDate),
                        new SqlParameter("@isActive", salesTerritories.IsActive));


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_CreateNewSalesTerritory
    @orgId              VARCHAR(255), 
    @salesTerritoryName VARCHAR(255), 
    @createdBy          VARCHAR(255), 
    @createdDate        DATETIME,
    @updatedBy          VARCHAR(255),
    @updatedDate        DATETIME,
    @isActive           BIT,
    @identity           INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO SalesTerritory (OrganizationId, Name, IsActive, 
                                CreatedBy, CreatedDate, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate)
    VALUES (@orgId, @salesTerritoryName, @isActive, 
            @createdBy, @createdDate, @updatedBy, @updatedDate);

    --SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    --RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    --SELECT @@IDENTITY;
    SET @identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END;

RETURN @identity
```

I expected to get the new inserted ID value for that record, instead, I get the default value of 0 on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would call such a stored procedure in "pure" ADO.NET using the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` method on the `SqlCommand` object - since it's an `INSERT` statement.

But now, your stored procedure is actually **returning** some data - so you really need to treat this like a "normal" `SELECT` stored procedure.

Assuming you're always returning just the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` value - preferably like this:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

which is just one single value - you can use the `.ExecuteScalar()` method on the `SqlCommand` object - something like this:

```
object returned = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (returned != null)
{
    int newIdValue = Convert.ToInt32(returned);
}
// else -> nothing was returned, so most likely no row has been inserted -> handle it appropriately
```

So maybe you already have a "wrapper" method for `.ExecuteScalar()` on your `DataManager.Db` object - or maybe you need to add it. Give it a try - I'm pretty sure this will solve the issue.

I would avoid using the `RETURN ...` statement - SQL Server stored procedure by default will always return the number of rows that were affected by your stored procedure - don't change that "standard" behavior, if you can.